# Difference between an Express server and an embedded server in spring boot

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, express

I've started learning Spring Boot coming from a NodeJS/Express background and I'm wondering what's the difference between the server that we create ourselves in an express app that listens on a certain port, and the Tomcat server in a spring application also called a container ? Why can't we do the same in a spring boot application where we create the server ourselves ?

```js
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server listening on port 3000"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Spring Ecosystem. We hope you enjoy your stay!

My first bit of advice, forget everything you know about Express because Spring is very different. I have not used Express in a while, but I remember it had a very programmatic approach. While that is possible in Spring, the most popular approach is declarative with annotations. Or, if you are old and like old technology, you can configure everything with XML.

What's Tomcat? Tomcat is a implementation of various Jakarta EE (formally Java EE) specifications. Depending on the Spring Boot version, you may see packages that start with `jakarta` or `javax`. Tomcat implements, Jakarta Servlet, Server Pages, Expression Language, WebSocket, Annotations, and Authentications. You can read more about each specification [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/). Note: Spring Boot by itself does not necessary use all of these modules and mostly Spring has many abstraction layers on top of them anyway, so you rarely will work with Tomcat directly. Specifically, `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is the Spring module that uses Tomcat, and is most often included as a transitive dependency through `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Now, to answer your question...

Spring Boot Web configures Tomcat for you. You can definitely override this behavior! One basic way is through configuration properties. Anything under `server.tomcat`. A good IDE should autocomplete and show you the options. You can also change the address and port of the Tomcat server with `server.address` and `server.port`. Another popular property developers change is `server.error.whitelabel.enabled`. They set it to `false` and provide their own error page. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page) is a great example. By the way, [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/) offers a lot of free Spring tutorials and guides. It is a great place to get started. They also offer paid courses with certifications.

FYI, you do not have to use Tomcat. Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! So basically Spring Boot takes care of everything :)) Hope I'll get enough knowledge to work with it in the future :)

Comment: @M.EH Exactly; Spring takes care of mostly everything. It is a pattern called [Inversion of Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). That what Spring IoC stands for. Glad I could help!

Comment: I would like to add to my last comment. While Spring does take care of mostly everything with sometimes dozens of layers of abstraction, it almost always allows you to customize each level of abstraction.